# In tomcat i write tomcat:run , what should be in case of glass fish when building maven project in eclipse?

Tags: java, tomcat, aero-glass

What i should write if i am using Glasss Fish in Goal Text Field when i am building maven project in eclipse , just like i am writing tomcat:run when using tomcat server ?

Dummy Code :

```
 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("F:\\vector_documents\\DevTest.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            fbw.write(""+ colList.get(i).get(0)+"");
            fbw.write("^");
            fbw.write(""+ colList.get(i).get(1)+"");
            fbw.write("^");
            fbw.write(""+ colList.get(i).get(2)+"");
            fbw.write("^");
            fbw.write(""+ colList.get(i).get(3)+"");
            fbw.write("^");
            fbw.write(""+ colList.get(i).get(4)+"");
            fbw.newLine();
```

Comment: Please ignore above code only i need  replacement of tomcat:run for glassfish server

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on which maven plugin you configured for Glassfish integration.

If you are using `org.glassfish:maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin` to provide an embedded Glassfish server it would be:

```
mvn clean package embedded-glassfish:run
```

The plugins gives you few other options as per [docs](https://javalibs.com/plugin/org.glassfish.embedded/maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin).

Comment: Finally I resolved my issue by following steps : 1. Right Click on project ,2. Go to Run As , 3.Maven Clean then ,4. Maven installed and then re restart glassfish server .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved my issue by following steps :

1. Right Click on project,
2. Go to Run As,

3.Maven Clean,

4.Maven installed,

5.Re restart glassfish server